# ASP Checkbox long text is not aligned

Tags: html, css, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am using a checkbox in which the text is long. I would like to make the text in both lines aligned. That is, in both lines the text should start at the same line. Please help me

[image]

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" Width="400px" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cb1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Text="This is very long This is very long This is very long This is very long This is very long This is very long" Value="cb1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

asp:CheckBox generates an input and a label. You can add css to the label. For align, you must add width to the lable.

```
label{width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}
```

Add CSS like this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" Width="400px" runat="server" CssClass="cb" Text="This is very long This is very long This is very long This is very long This is very long This is very long" Value="cb1" />

<style type="text/css">
    .cb label{width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, you must add it to your css file

Comment: Yes.. It is working. But the thing is it is affecting all the check boxes. How can I confine this to a single checkbox?

Comment: Thanks.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It is not a best practice but the quick - and working - solution is to override the bootstrap template that comes with Visual Studio.  Specifically, you add this css:

```
  .chkbx_inline_top label {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline!important;
  }
```

Then you reference the css class in the asp:checkbox component:

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="foo" runat="server" CssClass="chkbx_inline_top" Text="bar" />
```

This will allow the text to wrap to the next line instead of using a line break.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a `<div>` container and set a `width` with css.

```css
.container{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I have solution with asp:checkbox ?

Comment: The same. Add a div with a width